# How to map/collect with index in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, indexing

What is the easiest way to convert

```
[x1, x2, x3, ... , xN]
```

to

```
[[x1, 2], [x2, 3], [x3, 4], ... , [xN, N+1]]
```

Answer (score 923, accepted):

If you're using ruby 1.8.7 or 1.9, you can use the fact that iterator methods like `each_with_index`, when called without a block, return an `Enumerator` object, which you can call `Enumerable` methods like `map` on. So you can do:

```
arr.each_with_index.map { |x,i| [x, i+2] }
```

In 1.8.6 you can do:

```
require 'enumerator'
arr.enum_for(:each_with_index).map { |x,i| [x, i+2] }
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me a pointer to documentation for `.each_with_index.map` ?

Comment: In this case `map` is a function of what ?

Comment: @Misha: `map` is a method of `Enumerable` as always. `each_with_index`, when called without a block, returns an `Enumerator` object (in 1.8.7+), which mixes in `Enumerable`, so you can call `map`, `select`, `reject` etc. on it just like on an array, hash, range etc.

Comment: IMO this is simpler and better-reading in 1.8.7+: `arr.map.with_index{ |o,i| [o,i+2] }`

Comment: @Phrogz: `map.with_index` doesn't work in 1.8.7 (`map` returns an array when called without a block in 1.8).

Comment: Oops; good to know. I moved from 1.8.6 to 1.9 and have never seen the use of 1.8.7 since. My apologies to those who use 1.8.7.

Comment: only semi related, this also has some good info on enumerator: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/199584

Comment: Important to note this doesn't work with .map! if you want to directly affect the array you're looping on.

Comment: x and i is not descriptive enough for the purpose of answering general questions. It might serve you as your personal convention, but I am not certain i refers to index.

Answer (score 304):

Ruby has [Enumerator#with_index(offset = 0)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index), so first convert the array to an enumerator using [Object#to_enum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-to_enum) or [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
[:a, :b, :c].map.with_index(2).to_a
#=> [[:a, 2], [:b, 3], [:c, 4]]
```

Comment: I believe this is the better answer, because it will work with map! `foo = ['d'] * 5; foo.map!.with_index { |x,i| x * i }; foo #=> ["", "d", "dd", "ddd", "dddd"]`

Answer (score 201):

In ruby 1.9.3 there is a chainable method called `with_index` which can be chained to map.

For example:

```
array.map.with_index { |item, index| ... }
```

Answer (score 19):

Over the top obfuscation:

```
arr = ('a'..'g').to_a
indexes = arr.each_index.map(&2.method(:+))
arr.zip(indexes)
```

Comment: Andrew must have great job security! :)

Answer (score 14):

I have always enjoyed the syntax of this style:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.each_with_index.map { |el, index| el + index }
# => [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Invoking `each_with_index` gets you an enumerator you can easily map over with your index available.

Comment: how is this different form [the answer, given almost 5 years before yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4697573/1772830)?

Answer (score 9):

Here are two more options for 1.8.6 (or 1.9) without using enumerator:

```
# Fun with functional
arr = ('a'..'g').to_a
arr.zip( (2..(arr.length+2)).to_a )
#=> [["a", 2], ["b", 3], ["c", 4], ["d", 5], ["e", 6], ["f", 7], ["g", 8]]

# The simplest
n = 1
arr.map{ |c| [c, n+=1 ] }
#=> [["a", 2], ["b", 3], ["c", 4], ["d", 5], ["e", 6], ["f", 7], ["g", 8]]
```

Answer (score 4):

A fun, but useless way to do this:

```
az  = ('a'..'z').to_a
azz = az.map{|e| [e, az.index(e)+2]}
```

Comment: Why the hate? It is a functioning way of doing this AND I even say that is is a silly way to achieve the results.

Comment: the call to #index means this is now an O(N^2) loop also why the +2 ? :)

Comment: As I write `A fun, but useless way`. `+2` is to create the output the OP asks for

Comment: Fun and useless is different from "really inefficient and poor programming practice"

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
p [a, (2...a.size+2).to_a].transpose
```

Answer (score 2):

```
module Enumerable
  def map_with_index(&block)
    i = 0
    self.map { |val|
      val = block.call(val, i)
      i += 1
      val
    }
  end
end

["foo", "bar"].map_with_index {|item, index| [item, index] } => [["foo", 0], ["bar", 1]]
```

Comment: This might be an easier way to go for 1.8.6 and 1.8.7 (yes some of us still use it) instead of having to use weirder stuff like `each_with_index.map` etc. and even those of us on newer versions might prefer it to having to use map.with_index FWIW :)

Answer (score 1):

I often do this:

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"]

(0...arr.length).map do |int|
  [arr[int], int + 2]
end

#=> [["a", 2], ["b", 3], ["c", 4]]
```

Instead of directly iterating over the elements of the array, you're iterating over a range of integers and using them as the indices to retrieve the elements of the array.

Comment: If you read the other answers, I hope you now realise there are better approaches. So not sure why you needed to add this.

Comment: If Andrew Grimm's answer deserves ten votes, then this one deserves at least one!