# Capitalize, swapcase and reverse in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a challenging Ruby problem:

I want to convert "howdy" to "YDWOh" and "how are you" to "uoy era WOh".

which is essentially capitalize, swapcase and reverse functions. Capitalize and swapcase is only for the first word of the sentence. How do I do this when I have more than one word in the sentence?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a normal situation. Is it homework or a programming challenge? If so, in either case, you should figure it out for yourself. That's the point of homework and programming challenges.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following steps:

1. `capitalize` your string
2. `split(' ')` your string into an array with words
3. Use [`each_with_index.map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697557/how-to-map-with-index-in-ruby) to go over each word in the array
4. Use `swapcase` on only the first word of the array
5. `join(' ')` the array back into a string
6. `reverse` the string

Comment: @Linuxios, but I didn't add the code on purpose... so that there was at least something left for him to figure out by himself.

Comment: Sorry. I'll revert. Someone bellow told me I should edit my answer of code into your answer as it was using your steps. I'll revert.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below:

```
a = "how are you"
p a.gsub(a.split[0...1].join(' '),a.split[0...1].join(' ').capitalize.swapcase).reverse
```

Output:

```
"uoy era WOh"
```