# Deleting Values in an Array Traversing it in Reverse in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array:

```
arr = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

and I want to modify my array by deleting at every step of -5, i.e., `arr[-5], arr[-10], arr[-15]` so the original array `arr`after deletion equals:

```
arr = [8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

What I've been told is its not good practice to delete from an array that you're iterating through. Are there any clean solutions?

Comment: `delete_at` accepts index. Give it an index.

Comment: Instead of mutating source array, build a copy of it, without those elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is complicated to modify an array while iterating from the same side as the indices are counted. In other words, when you have positive indices, you should not iterate from the head to the tail while modifying; if you have negative indices, you should not iterate from the tail to the head. Otherwise, there is no problem.

Since you have negative indices, it is crucial that you modify from the head toward the tail.

```
[-15, -10, -5].each{|i| arr.delete_at(i)}
# => [8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

Comment: @user2684075, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19320451/693538) for the development of __sawa__'s idea (without hard-coded numbers)

Answer (score 2):

Just a modification of **@tihom**'s answer, not relying on uniqueness, but using some ideas from ["How to map with index in Ruby?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4697557/693538):

```
>> arr.each_with_index.select{ |x, i| (arr.count-i)%5 != 0 }.map{ |x,i| x }
=> [8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

Step by step it does:

1. `.each_with_index` returns an Enumerator, which yields pairs of value and its index like `[7, 0], [8, 1], [9, 2], ...`
2. `.select{...}` selects those pairs `[x,i]` for which `count - i` is not divisible by 5 *(it would be all except `count - 5`, `count - 10`, etc)*
3. `.map{ |x,i| x }` transforms each pair to just its first element.

Not the most efficient, but at least clear, I think

**BONUS:**

I *am sure* that it is better to create a new array by some tranformation (in a functional-style) than modify it in-place, but if you insist on "in-place", here is a modification of **@sawa**'s answer without hard-coded digits:

```
>> (-arr.count..-5).select {|i| i % 5 == 0}.each{|i| arr.delete_at(i)}
=> [-15, -10, -5]
>> arr
=> [8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

Here we have a range from -size to -5, select only indices that are divisible by 5, and delete by them. As he said, it is important here to delete *exactly* in this order. But still to protect yourself from possible mistakes, I think it is safer yo **never delete from an array you are iterating through** and instead produce a new array (like in first method). Why complicate? ;)

Comment: `(-arr.count..-5).select {|i| i % 5 == 0}` could be written as `(-arr.count).step(-5, 5)`.

Comment: @undur_gongor, not exactly: if array has 16 elements, it would produce    [-16, -11, -6], not [-15, -10, -5]. But if the OP can swear its size is divisible by 5, it's quite a good simplification. Thanks, didn't know about `Numeric#step`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
p arr.reverse.each_slice(5).map{|x|x[0..-2]}.flatten.reverse
# => [8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

Comment: I get a different result with the example input and your code: `[7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22]`. And that's normal. How should the 7 get dropped with your approach?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post without thinking, I think the best way is to the reverse the table first and reverse it back. Made an edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.reject.with_index{|x,i| (i-arr.count) % 5 == 0 }
 => [8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

Comment: Still a good idea, I used it in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19320451/693538), which doesn't assume uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19317883/908515:

```
arr.reverse.reject.with_index { | _, i | (i + 1) % 5 == 0 }.reverse
# i.e. arr.reverse.drop_every(5).reverse
```

If you want to modify the original array in-place, you can do

```
arr.reverse!.reject!.with_index { | _, i | (i + 1) % 5 == 0 }.reverse!
```

This is safe because the enumerator indices (`i`) are independent of the array indices.