# How to refer the index of an element in Array#delete_if

Tags: ruby, methods

I want to build a custom method `Array#drop_every(n)` (I know it's monkey patching, I am doing this for a homework), which returns a new array omitting every nth element:

```
[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].drop_every(2) # [4, 15, 23]
```

I want to implement it with `Array#delete_if`, but by referring to the index and not to the element itself, (similar to `each_index`) something like this:

```
def drop_every(step)
  self.delete_if { |index| index % step == 0 }
end
```

How do I do this? I don't insist on using `delete_if`, I also looked at `drop_while` and `reject`, other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: make sure to see the updated answer as one before did not work for step > 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def drop_every(step)
  reject.with_index { |x,i| (i+1) % step == 0 }
end

[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].reject.with_index{|x,i| (i+1) % 2 ==  0}
# => [4, 15, 23]

[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].reject.with_index{|x,i| (i+1) % 3 ==  0}
# => [4, 8, 16, 23]
```

Comment: I like the short conciseness of your solution, but the method returns exactly the opposite of what I want - it returns every nth element and I want it to omit every nth element.

Comment: @AlexPopov changed by solution as finally got what you meant...the previous one did not work for steps more than 2

Answer (score 3):

You can use `with_index` method that returns enumerator, filter your collection and then get rid of the indexes.

```
class Array
  def drop_every(step)
    self.each.with_index.select { |_, index| index % step == 0 }.map(&:first)
  end
end

[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].drop_every(2) # => [4, 15, 23]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `values_at` method to selectively filter out indices which you want.

```
class Array
  def drop_every(step)
    self.values_at(*(0...self.size).find_all{ |x| (x+1) % step != 0 })
  end    
end
```

The answer was accepted while I was typing it. I will post it anyways.

Comment: use `self.size -1` else it will return `nil` for last element in some cases.

Comment: @tihom I used  `...`(half open interval)

Comment: nice..did not know that syntax...my bad

Answer (score 1):

```
def drop_every step
  delete_if.with_index(1){|_, i| i.%(step).zero?}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Array
  def drop_every(step)
    self.each_slice(step).flat_map{|slice| slice[0..-2]}
  end
end

p [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].drop_every(2) #=> [4, 15, 23]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd extend the [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html) mixin instead:

```
module Enumerable
  def drop_every(step)
    return to_enum(:drop_every, step) unless block_given?
    each.with_index(1) do |o, i|
      yield o unless i % step == 0
    end
  end
end

(1..10).drop_every(3) { |a| p a }
# outputs below
1
2
4
5
7
8
10
```