# Time zone dropdown where select value is index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a select dropdown for time_zones in my user profile but I need the list and indexes to match up because I'm not using text, I'm using an integer for to store the zones in my database. I did that so I could display it as a dropdown in rails admin instead of a text input.

**User:**

```
validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, in: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map { |z| z.name }, 
message: "is not a valid time zone", 
allow_blank: true

 # This allows me to display the time_zone as a dropdown in rails admin instead of a text box
 TIMEZONES = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map { |z| z.name }
 def time_zone_enum
   TIMEZONES.each_with_index.to_a
 end
```

**View:**

```
<%= f.collection_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map { |z| z.name }, value, name %>

 # I don't know how to get the value to be an index of the map operation and to display the name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try map.each_with_index as described here: [How to map with index in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697557/how-to-map-with-index-in-ruby)

```
<%= f.collection_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map.each_with_index { |z, i| i.to_s.concat(" #{z.name}") }, name %>
```

You may need to modify that code to work in your rails application, but calling each_with_index on your map should give you a second parameter which will contain the index of your hash.