# How to prepend elements in array ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to prepend 'n-' in the elements of an array being n the number of the index of the element and after that reverse it
the array is
`["Abricot du Laudot", "Black Caviar", "Brigadier Gerard", "Coup de Folie"]`
and I need it to be like that
`["4-Brigadier Gerard!", "3-Coup de Folie!", "2-Black Caviar!", "1-Abricot du Laudot!"]`
so far I've tried
`race_array.map! { |horse| horse.prepend() }.reverse!`
but could not find a way to put the number index into the prepend function or using each method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the index injected into the `map` block, you need to call an enumerator method that sends the index to the block. Here are a few options:

```rb
race_array = ["Abricot du Laudot", "Black Caviar", "Brigadier Gerard", "Coup de Folie"]

# Use `each_with_index` before calling `map`
race_array.each_with_index.map{ |name, i| "#{i+1}-#{name}" }.reverse
# => ["4-Coup de Folie", "3-Brigadier Gerard", "2-Black Caviar", "1-Abricot du Laudot"]

# Use `with_index` after calling `map`
race_array.map.with_index{ |name, i| "#{i+1}-#{name}" }.reverse
# => ["4-Coup de Folie", "3-Brigadier Gerard", "2-Black Caviar", "1-Abricot du Laudot"]

# Similarly, you can call `with_index` with an offset:
race_array.map.with_index(1){ |name, i| "#{i}-#{name}" }.reverse
# => ["4-Coup de Folie", "3-Brigadier Gerard", "2-Black Caviar", "1-Abricot du Laudot"]
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697557/how-to-map-with-index-in-ruby) for more information.

And for a more "exotic" solution (though less readable), you could combine an index with each element of the array, and then join the result:

```rb
(1..race_array.length).zip(race_array).map{|x| x.join('-')}.reverse
```

Comment: Instead of `"#{i}-#{name}"`, maybe it is clearer to write something like `name.prepend.(i+'-')`. This is of course a matter of taste. In addition, there is a functional difference: If `name` is not a `String`, but, for instance, `nil` or a number, this would be silently accepted in your code, while the solution with `prepend` would raise an exception. Which one is the desired behaviour here, I can't tell.

Comment: Sorry, should of course be `name.prepend.("#{i}-")`.